# Matlab - Evaluating nested anonymous function with arrayfun

Tags: matlab, function, loops, nested, anonymous

I want to evaluate an anonymous function in Matlab, which again consists of several anonymous functions.

Please excuse the somewhat chaotic labeling of the variables as this is a strongly simplified version of the original problem:

```
C.B_MT = 2; C.T = 24; C.OM_MT = 1/24; C.P_WTmax = 2;
ub = 3;
ObjFcn = @(x) CostFcn1(x,C,ub);
x = 1:4;
fit = ObjFcn(x)
```

The function that `ObjFcn` calls is the following:

```
function F = CostFcn1(x,C,ub)
    F = f_t(x,C,ub) + OM_DG(C) + TCPD_BES(x,C);
    function ft = f_t(x,C,ub)
        N = cell(1,2);
        ft = x(2)*C.B_MT+ub;
        for i = 1:2
            N{i} = C.B_MT*x(i+2)+ub;
        end
        ft = ft(x) + sum(arrayfun(@(N_q) N_q{1}(x), N));
    end

    function om_dg = OM_DG(C)
        om_dg = C.T*C.OM_MT;
    end

    function tcpd = TCPD_BES(x,C)
        tcpd = x(1)*C.P_WTmax;
    end
end
```

When I run the code without the part of the for-loop and `arrayfun`, it works without a problems (`fit = 10`). With `arrayfun`, however, I get an error. How can I change the code that `arrayfun` doesn't cause any problems?

Comment: the problem is with the part where you are trying to access `ft(x)` and `N_q{1}(x)`. Replace these parts with `ft` and `N_q{1}` and you should be good to go. Also, unless you need to do anything else in the three nested functions you have. you can get rid of these functions and just directly use the statements inside of them. that will save you a lot of overhead

Comment: Thank you @ammportal! This little tweak did the trick. The real code is finally running smoothly.

Comment: @ammportal, please consider creating an answer or the OP (Maluquinho) may do it himself.

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Please consider accepting it if it helps you @Maluquinho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the part where you are trying to access `ft(x)` and `N_q{1}(x)`. Replace these parts with `ft` and `N_q{1}` and you should be good to go.

Also, unless you need to do anything else in the three nested functions you have. you can get rid of these functions and just directly use the statements inside of them. that will save you a lot of overhead. Here I add the optimized code:

```
function F = CostFcn1(x,C,ub)
    om_dg = C.T*C.OM_MT;
    tcpd = x(1)*C.P_WTmax;
    N = zeros(1,2);
    ft = x(2)*C.B_MT+ub;
    for i = 1:2
        N(i) = C.B_MT*x(i+2)+ub;
    end
    ft = ft + sum(N);
    F = ft + om_dg + tcpd;
end
```

This should work if your original code is similar (the variables used here have the same type as in your original code) to the one you have posted